# Pagination Wont Display Next Page Results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, twig, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

October has a [Scope Pagination](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes) feature, but it lacks the functionality I need, so I have to use Laravel to return the results and pagination.

I have a galley with categories and image database records.

I'm trying to get the `:category` Identifier `nature` from the URL to filter back database results.

---

**Problem**

The code returns the nature images and displays pagination. But when I click a page number the url changes to `?page=2` or `/2`, but the page button stays on `1` and the records/images don't change.

Its like the php resets on the next page and shows page 1 results again.

[image]

---

### OctoberCMS

URL
`localhost/gallery/nature`

Identifiers
`/gallery/:category?latest/:page?`

---

### Laravel

Get all image records in category nature.

I put this code in my Page `gallery.htm`.

```
$category = $this->param('category');
$this['scopeCategory'] = Gallery::where('category', $category)->paginate(5);
```

---

### Twig

Display the images with pagination.

**List Images**

```
{% for image in scopeCategory %}
    <img src="example.com/{{ image.name }}.jpg">
{% endfor %}
```

**Simple Pagination**

```
<< 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 >>

{{ scopeCategory.render|raw }}
```

**Custom Pagination**

```
← Prev 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 Next →

{% if scopeCategory.LastPage > 1 %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if scopeCategory.CurrentPage > 1 %}
            <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (scopeCategory.CurrentPage-1) }) }}">← Prev</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for page in 1..scopeCategory.LastPage %}
            <li class="{{ scopeCategory.CurrentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if scopeCategory.LastPage > scopeCategory.CurrentPage %}
            <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (scopeCategory.CurrentPage+1) }) }}">Next →</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: have you try `localhost/gallery/nature:page?` or you can also use the builder component that you can plug on every models

Comment: @Pierre-AndréVullioud nature:page? gives the same result. The builder's scope won't allow me to use the :category identifier, so I have to use Laravel code instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to pass the page number directly to the paginator by specifying it as a second parameter [(see docs)](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/pagination). The following code should fix your issue.

```
$page= $this->param('page');
$category = $this->param('category');
$this['scopeCategory'] = Gallery::where('category', $category)->paginate(5, $page);
```